# Refresh list in ng-repeat without onclick funtion

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello i am trying to display data from server in Angularjs App, where i got the data and use ng-repeat to display it through controller.

Here is how my controller looks like:

```
module.controller('FiveReasons', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $sce) {
ons.ready(function() {
                    $scope.reasonsLists = {};
                   var reasonsListing = $http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients");
                    reasonsListing.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data[0].post_title);
                        $scope.reasonsLists = data;
                        $scope.spinner = false;
                    });
                    reasonsListing.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                        alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
                    });   
    });
});
```

But when the `ng-repeat` finish loading, the data is not displaying.

Here is how my `ng-repeat` is:

```
  <ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll fullscreen var="carousel" name="FiveRes" class="FiveRes">

        <div ng-repeat="reasonsList in reasonsLists">

          <ons-carousel-item style="background: #09a4c0;" >
            <div class="item-label">Number : {{reasonsList}}</div>

          </ons-carousel-item>

        </div>


          <ons-carousel-cover></ons-carousel-cover>
        </ons-carousel>
```

How can i now refresh the list once the data is there. Like we do "trigger("refresh")" in jquery.

After running ng-repeat, this is how i get the value but the screen is going blank.

[image]

Thank you! (In advance)

Comment: are you sure that the ons.ready event is actually firing? Angular uses data-binding, so any time you update something in the controller, it should update in the dom. I think with the angular $http service, you don't have to use $scope.$apply(); to get any changes, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes its firing. I did console.log on that

Comment: Because this is happening inside of an ons.ready function, you may have to run a $scope.$apply(); to get the data to update in dom.

Comment: Where should i use this? Because i am getting some error on using $scope.$apply();

Comment: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress this is the error i am getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
module.controller('FiveReasons', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $sce) {
       ons.ready(function() {
           $scope.reasonsLists = {};
           var reasonsListing = $http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients");
           reasonsListing.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 console.log(data[0].post_title);
                 $scope.reasonsLists = data;
                 $scope.spinner = false;
           });
           reasonsListing.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
           }); 
           //ADD this to notify Angular for the changes and run a digest cycle
           $scope.$digest();  
      });
});
```

This is happening because the event (`ons-ready`) handler will not start a new `$digest` cycle.

To display the data without having to call `$digest()`, remove the `ons-ready` callback and execute your code directly in the controllers body. Like the example bellow:

```
module.controller('FiveReasons', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $sce) {
       $scope.reasonsLists = {};
       var reasonsListing = $http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients");
       reasonsListing.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             console.log(data[0].post_title);
             $scope.reasonsLists = data;
             $scope.spinner = false;
       });
       reasonsListing.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
             alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
       }); 
       //No need to call $digest
});
```

UPDATE: Check this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVKXOj) which is a simplified version of your code that shows only the issue. Remove `$scope.$digest()` from the comments to see the `carousel` working.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case I'd eliminate the use of ready and call your code using ng-init.

```
module.controller('FiveReasons', function($scope, $http) {
this.reasonsLists = {};
$scope.getReasonsLists = function() {
    $scope.reasonsLists = {};
    $http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients")
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data[0].post_title);
            $scope.reasonsLists = data;
            $scope.spinner = false;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
        });
};
```

});

then in your html on the table tag just add ng-init="getReasonsLists()"

Comment: copy the code snippet from the question and not from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A "refresh" should not be necessary as angular uses a different approach. After certain events like "click" or the return of a $http-promise, angular goes through the binded variables and checks if they have changed - and if so - changes the DOM.

In your case I think the promise is returning before you add the success-callback. Try chaining it like:

```
$http.get("http://vbought.com/design_14/index.php/design_ci/post/Clients").success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data[0].post_title);
    $scope.reasonsLists = data;
    $scope.spinner = false;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("Can Not load the address Ajax");
});
```

In other cases you can use $scope.$apply() but I think this should tell you, that you can't nest $digests as there should be one going on after a $http-request.

Comment: Yes i tried. But yes i guess <ons-carousel> is running before the $http-promise completes.

Still have save issue. Content is not displaying.

Comment: How about trying to wrap all inside of ons.ready in a setTimeout?